# How to solve modulo math equation in RSA algorithm?

Tags: computer-networks

$(3 \cdot d) \mod 8=1$. I know the answer is $d=3$ by common sense. But what is the mathematical approach to solve this problem? How do I solve this mathematically?

How do we get this value of 125^107 mod 187=5?
[image: This figure]

Comment: If there are two questions, ask them separately. And, do not use images in your questions, see [this](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/a/753/107966).

Answer (score 1):

Use [Extended gcd algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Euclidean_algorithm). The time complexity is $O(\log n)$.

Answer (score 0):

We know that $gcd(3,8)=1$ since $3$ is a prime, and therefore $3$ has one and *unique* inverse under multiplication modulo $8$.

As you have seen, its not hard to guess that $3$ is its own inverse, that is, $x=3$ is the solution for the equation:
$$3x\equiv1 \mod 8$$

Since there is only one and unique solution, we know that $3$ is the only solution.

Its important to note that "guessing" a solution and verifying it, is a totally fine thing to do, and it is totally "mathematical".

Comment: Can you solve this? (d*7) mod 60=1

Comment: Yea my bad. I was confused with some other computational problem